# Java Issues in Microsoft Internet Explorer & Firefox with Java 6 Standard

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, internet-explorer, java

I have a user on Windows XP SP3 running Java 6 Standard Edition Update 20 (build 1.6.0_20-b02).

The issue is that when Java applets load the Java splash screen is very shaky (I will have to take a screenshot if you don't know what I am talking about) and than the Java applet screen does not show properly.  The Applet we use most is for a security camera and you can't view the camera properly because of the Java issues.

I have uninstalled Java and re-installed and still having the same issue.

I do not see any errors on the Java Console, and this only happens on his computer I am running the same version of Java and the browsers and do not have the same issue on my machine.

Comment: Could you take a screenshot just so we know what you mean exactly?

Comment: http://www.imagebam.com/image/c14cca87760913

When Java loads that is what the screen looks like.  After that the applets do not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The Java plugin might not have been correctly updated, and some old files might be trailing somewhere.

I would suggest uninstalling Firefox, cleaning out its directories, then reinstalling it and the Java JRE. If this works for Firefox, then something similar needs to be done to IE, where it's a bit more complex.

Just in case: Do you have Microsoft's Java [installed](http://java.com/en/download/help/uninstall_msvm.xml) ?

Comment: Thank you, Microsoft Java doesn't appear to be installed.  I removed Firefox and Java (including going through the registry and removing any trace of Java) and I am still getting the issue.  It is very frustrating as I have now spend a couple of hours on something that should be very simple.